# Question about a four degre extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ Involving polynomials.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let $L$ be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ and $L$ is normal over $\mathbb{Q}$. So $L$ is splitting field of a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

My question is: Is there a way to determine the degree of $f$?

I have no another hypotesis about $f$, so for instance we can get $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ and $f(x) = (x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ or $f(x) = (x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x-1)$.  This way, it seems like $f$ could have degree whatever we want, as long as it's bigger than four. I guess we need another hypotesis, maybe $f$ must be irreducible, what do you think??

Also, I don't know if it is usefull, but since $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ has four degree and it is normal (and of course, separable) we have $\vert Gal(L:\mathbb{Q})\vert=4$.

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: I think that irreducibility here not suffice to have that the degree of $f$ is the degree of the extension, you should add that $f$ contain a primitive element as a root. What can be said is that deg($f$)|$[L:\mathbb{Q}]$. If splitting field means that $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(f)}\supseteq L$ (generally i think you just have the opposite inclusion) you should be fine.

Comment: Given a polynomial $f$ the splitting field is generated by his roots, so, as you pointed out, multiply by polinomials that splits in $\mathbb{Q}$ or that also splits in any subfield of $L$ does not change the splitting field but change $f$. Do you want to charcterize all polynomials such that L is its splitting field?